# Architecture of IMCs(Integrated Memory Controllers) in latest Intel processors

Tags: memory, intel, xeon-phi

I have been looking into Xeon architecture for a server application. I saw that Xeon supports Quad channel architecture with 3 DIMMs per channel. I have attached a page from Intel's Xeon datasheet.

[image: source: intel]
I got this from :
https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/xeon-e5-1600-2600-vol-2-datasheet.pdf Page 392  Section 4.4.

I have a doubt on the statement about DRAM controllers sharing a common address decode and DMA engine.

- If I have 4 cores on the Xeon processor, will I be able to access the 4 DDR channels simultaneously? For example can I use one CPU core to write to DDR channel 1 and another cpu core to read from DDR channel 2 simultaneously?

> controllers share a common address decode

- Also I assume the above statement means that I can have a DMA engine for a single channel at a time?

Appreciate any support.